# How to prove inverse direction for correlation coefficient?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation, covariance

To show: If |Cor(X,Y)| = 1, then there exists *a, b ∈ R* s.t ***Y = bX + a***. Any ideas or hints to proceed?

Basically, I've to prove that if the absolute value of correlation b/w two random variables is 1, then they **should** be linearly related.

So far,

$$ |cor(X, Y)| = 1 $$

$$ \frac{|Cov(X, Y)|}{|\sigma(X) \sigma(Y)|} = 1 $$

$$ |Cov(X, Y)| = |\sigma(X) \sigma(Y)| $$

How to proceed further?

Comment: Hint: when is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality actually an _equality_?

Comment: Your statement is only almost sure: consider $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$ when $X$ is rational and $Y=+X$ when $X$ is irrational

Comment: @Watson: Wiki says the equality holds when they are "linearly related". But I've to show/prove this formally and I don't know how to proceed.